# Rundeck running behind apache proxy does not show "Resource Node Models"

Tags: apache, proxy, rundeck

I have a rundeck server which is running on server A with 10.10.100.120 VIP. I configured also a proxy on Server B having ip address 192.168.38.205.

So, Proxy server redirects incoming traffic to VIP:4440 in order to access Rundeck application.
To get there I have 2 options; Using application's VIP or Server B's ip address (proxy server).

Application server is a Centos 7, running Rundeck 3.0.22

Proxy server is a Centos 6 running apache 2.2

Here is my httpd configuration on proxy server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example: 
    ProxyPass / http://10.10.100.120:4440/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.10.100.120:4440/

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Proxy modules loaded:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
```

I followed instructions here:

From [Digital ocean's proxy guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-http-server-as-reverse-proxy-using-mod_proxy-extension)!

The problem is :

When I access the application from proxy and click on "Resource Model" tab in order to add node file under project > project settings > edit nodes, new window does not appear.

Normally, It should appear, by this way I could select the model that I want to use as node file.

Expected result:

[From_rundeck_Server1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa9eC.png)

[From_rundeck_server2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lADSV.png)

Proxy server problem:

[From_proxy_server1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnT5N.png)

[From_proxy_Server2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7Wvr.png)

Answer (score 0):

That's a Known Issue, to solve it change the `grails.serverURL` (rundeck-config.properties file usually at /etc/rundeck/rundeck-config.properties) value from "localhost" to your server hostname. Check this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rundeck-discuss/I94cVxK_6kQ/0a3PPyygAwAJ

Comment: Thanks ReinerRDECK. That's what I was looking for.
Alternatively, I've just added in my browser's proxy settings the IP of proxy server than access rundeck via VIP. It seems to be resolved now.